# Deserializing claims fails for Auth0 Token

Tags: jwt, auth0

I'm using auth0 and am passing the generated token to the backend for some processing.
I need to validate the token and fetch some data from it (mainly email).

Checking the JWT on jwt.io and it appears valid with all relevant information there.

I'm using the provided auth0 middleware https://github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware to parse the token on my end. Everything runs fine until it gets to `deserializeClaims`.

I'm then hit with: `could not get token claims: square/go-jose: unsupported key type/format)`

Even just some insight on how to better troubleshoot this would be helpful, as it stands, I have no idea what is wrong.

```
// ValidateToken validates the passed in JWT using the jose v2 package.
func (v *Validator) ValidateToken(ctx context.Context, tokenString string) (interface{}, error) {
    token, err := jwt.ParseSigned(tokenString)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not parse the token: %w", err)
    }

    if err = validateSigningMethod(string(v.signatureAlgorithm), token.Headers[0].Algorithm); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("signing method is invalid: %w", err)
    }

   
    registeredClaims, customClaims, err := v.deserializeClaims(ctx, token)  <- this fails
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to deserialize token claims: %w", err)
    }

    if err = validateClaimsWithLeeway(registeredClaims, v.expectedClaims, v.allowedClockSkew); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("expected claims not validated: %w", err)
    }

    if customClaims != nil {
        if err = customClaims.Validate(ctx); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("custom claims not validated: %w", err)
        }
    }

    validatedClaims := &ValidatedClaims{
        RegisteredClaims: RegisteredClaims{
            Issuer:    registeredClaims.Issuer,
            Subject:   registeredClaims.Subject,
            Audience:  registeredClaims.Audience,
            ID:        registeredClaims.ID,
            Expiry:    numericDateToUnixTime(registeredClaims.Expiry),
            NotBefore: numericDateToUnixTime(registeredClaims.NotBefore),
            IssuedAt:  numericDateToUnixTime(registeredClaims.IssuedAt),
        },
        CustomClaims: customClaims,
    }

    return validatedClaims, nil
}
```

`could not get token claims: square/go-jose: unsupported key type/format)`

Comment: What key type you used there. `getAccessTokenSilently` **or** `getAccessTokenWithPopup` **or** `getIdTokenClaims`.

Comment: @Kalana I used `getAccessTokenSilently`

Comment: use `getIdTokenClaims` option. Then it will work.

Comment: Issue with this is that getIdTokenClaims only gets the claims on the frontend, I needed to pass the token to the backend, validate it, do some work, and then send an updated response back.  For whatever reason, started working randomly without really understanding what I did differently.

Comment: It is because you send the `getIdTokenClaims token` to the backend instead of the `getAccessTokenSilently token`. You can clarify that by accessing this [site](https://jwt.io/) (Powered by Auth0 itself) and comparing both tokens.